# создание excel файла в питоне

Tags: python, xls, xlrd

Хочу создать xls файл, установил xlrd и xlwt

Пишу:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xlwt
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
workbook.save('my_file.xls')
```

получаю ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test2.py", line 4, in <module>
    workbook.save('my_file.xls')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/Workbook.py", line 710, in save
    doc.save(filename_or_stream, self.get_biff_data())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/Workbook.py", line 680, in get_biff_data
    self.__worksheets[self.__active_sheet].selected = True
IndexError: list index out of range
```

не очень понял ошибку, т.к за питон сегодня сел впервые

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно создать хотя бы одну вкладку в книге:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xlwt
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
workbook.add_sheet('my_sheet')
workbook.save('my_file.xls')
```